# Where can i find legacy wxPython 2.6.1.0 for mac?

Tags: macos, wxpython

Im trying to install [SPE (Stani's Python Editor)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/spe/) on a Mac running osx 10.9.2 Mavericks.
I seem to have a version of wxPython too advanced for the SPE.

```
Spe Warning: Spe was developped on wxPython v2.6.1.0., but v3.0.0.0. was found.
If you experience any problems please install wxPython v2.6.1.0.


SPE v0.8.2.a (c)2003-2005 www.stani.be

If spe fails to start:
 - type "pythonw SPE.py --debug > debug.txt 2>&1" at the command prompt
   (or if you use tcsh: "pythonw SPE.py --debug >& debug.txt")
 - send debug.txt with some info to spe.stani.be[at]gmail.com

If spe is unstable, try this interface from the preferences:
  "multiple with sash & tabs (mac default,linux default,windows)"


Spe Warning: Spe was developped on wxPython v2.6.1.0., but v3.0.0.0. was found.
If you experience any problems please install wxPython v2.6.1.0.

Blender support disabled (run SPE inside Blender to enable).

Encrypted debugging disabled. 
  If you prefer encrypted debugging, install the "Python Cryptography Toolkit"
  from http://www.amk.ca/python/code/crypto

Launching application...
```

By googling this, ive found some posts saying to just use the older wxPython.
But where do i find wxPython v2.6?
I cant seem to find previous versions on [wxPython's website](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php).

I need to install this to use pyBrain for my Machine Intelligence class.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need this for pyBrain - the other questions here just seem to need a plain pip install and no mention of wxPython

Comment: Im following our professors instructions.
He wants us to use SPE which requires wxPython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legacy installs are on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.6.1.0/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DigCamara: The essential part of the answer *is* the link. There's no real useful context that can be provided to a download link besides "I found it by doing *x*".

Comment: @nandhp : I think these answers should be judged by how they read even if the link they contain gets broken, for whatever reason. Imagine if a year from now someone finds this link and the project was deleted and/or moved from the site, maybe to github. Anyone with the same problem would be unable to solve their problem and be forced to ask the same question again, cluttering the answer-space.

Comment: I ran into alot of warnings/errors trying to install Python 2.3 to get this to work anyhow. So i will probably just not use the IDE. Thanks for the help anyhow.

Comment: i will accept once my edit is reviewed (just changed the wording). simple google search had already been done. link was overlooked.

Comment: Python 2.3 is obsolete it real cannot be used nowadays

Comment: @DigCamara in this case only the link matters - which is why the question is probably off topic